# Trouble matching strings (titles) using wp_query

Tags: php, sanitization

I'm repairing an old site on which we match the titles of two types of posts to link them together. There is a `wp_query` which uses `'title' => get_the_title()` to do this, but it only works some of the time.

My first solution was to clean the title string using `html_entity_decode()`. This works on 90% of cases and I need to retain this processing to deal with these posts.

However I am now stuck with a particular outlier, which has a title like this `It’s Raining Outside My Mother’s House`.

- If I compare `==` the two values, with no preprocessing, it returns true, but via the query it fails.
- If I paste the title value into the query it works, and if I use `addslashes()` it still works.
- But if I use `get_the_title()` in the query (as I need to for the final code) it fails, even if I use `addslashes()`.

Is there another function I need in order to clean the title string? Can you suggest an 'all cases' technique?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. After much digging I eventually came upon this:

`remove_filter ('the_title', 'wptexturize');`

Comment: Or instead of using `get_the_title()`, you can use [`get_post_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) to get the raw (unfiltered) value. :)

Comment: Ah, I did not know that would be unfiltered. Thanks Sally!